# ORDER BY ASC e DESC ao mesmo tempo

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso que os dados que possuírem `tr_color = success` sejam ordenados de maneira Decrescente **DESC** e os que não tiverem isso, que a coluna estiver vazia, seja ordena de maneira Ascendente **ASC**.

Estou montando a query desse jeito.

```
SELECT mc.competencia,
CASE
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'success'
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN ''
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'danger'
END AS tr_color
FROM movimento_cobranca AS mc
WHERE mc.matricula = 2035
ORDER BY tr_color
```

E esta me retornando no momento o seguinte resultado.

```
Competencia |  tr_color
-----------------------
0419              ""
0419              ""
0419              ""
0519              ""
0619              ""
0719              ""
0819              ""
0919              ""
1019              ""
1119              ""
1219              ""
0419              ""
0319              success
0118              success
0319              success
0219              success
0119              success
0218              success
0318              success
0418              success
0518              success
0618              success
0718              success
0818              success
0918              success
1018              success
1118              success
1218              success
```

Eu preciso retornar de modo que os que possuem **success** fique na seguinte ordem.

`0319 - 0219 - 0119 - 1218 - 1118` ...

E os que não possuem **success** continuem igual.

---

**EDIT SOLUÇÃO**

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT mc.competencia,
           CASE
             WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'success'
             WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN ''
             WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'danger'
             END AS tr_color
    FROM movimento_cobranca AS mc
    WHERE mc.matricula = 2035
      AND COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) > 0.0
    ORDER BY data_vencimento DESC
  ) AS p
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT mc.competencia,
         CASE
           WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'success'
           WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN ''
           WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'danger'
           END AS tr_color
  FROM movimento_cobranca AS mc
  WHERE mc.matricula = 2035
    AND COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0.0
  ORDER BY data_vencimento
)
```

Comment: É o mesmo campo que eles utilizam @rbz. Ai esta minha duvida em como fazer hahah

Comment: `SE talcoisa USE campo1 OU -campo2`  (note o sinal de - ) - Com case when ou equivalente em pgsql (em MySQL tem o IF, em T-SQL tem o IIF no 2012)

Comment: Você pode fazer o select do select e ordenar por aqueles campos como sugerido pelo @rbz

Comment: Eu havia tentado fazer um `UNION` mas sem sucesso, talvez pela minha falta de conhecimento em SQL.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti union tb serve bem, se puder deixar os 2 sets separados. SELECT campos WHERE tr_color = success ORDER BY campo1 ASC UNION SELECT campos WHERE tr_color <> success ORDER BY campo2 DESC (ajuste para seu DB)

Comment: Como ficaria o `CASE` ? `CASE WHEN tr_color <> 'success' THEN .... ` o que eu setaria no THEN?

Comment: @Bacco Não consigo fazer 2 ORDER BY no `Postgres` utilizando UNION.

Comment: Tente separar os select com (SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...) - Raramente uso pgsql, não gosto, pra falar a verdade, mal lembro das especificidades. Só quis realmente falar algo de antemão até que surja resposta oficial

Comment: @Bacco Entendo, pois é pgsql é bem chato na verdade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testa assim, se der certo eu comento a resposta.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT mc.competencia,
  (CASE
  WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'success'
  WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN ''
  WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'danger'
  END) AS tr_color
  FROM movimento_cobranca AS mc
  WHERE mc.matricula = 2035
  AND mc.valor_pago = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)
  ORDER BY tr_color DESC
  )
UNION ALL
  (
  SELECT mc.competencia,
  (CASE
  WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'success'
  WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN ''
  WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'danger'
  END) AS tr_color
  FROM movimento_cobranca AS mc
  WHERE mc.matricula = 2035
  AND mc.valor_pago <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)
  ORDER BY tr_color
  )
) AS tableAlias
```

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88316/discussion-on-answer-by-rbz-order-by-asc-e-desc-ao-mesmo-tempo)

Answer (score 1):

Execute a query abaixo onde foi criado uma coluna apenas para ordenação que transforma como negativo o valor da competência na ordenação atingindo o resultado desejado.

```
SELECT mc.competencia,
  CASE
     WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'success'
     WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN ''
     WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'danger'
  END AS tr_color,
  CASE
     WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN mc.competencia
     WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN mc.competencia*-1
     WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN mc.competencia
  END AS campo_ordenacao

FROM movimento_cobranca AS mc
WHERE mc.matricula = 2035
ORDER BY tr_color,campo_ordenacao
```

Veja o exemplo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0578f/1

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução seria repetir o `CASE` na cláusula `ORDER BY`, exemplo:

```
SELECT mc.competencia,
CASE
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'success'
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN ''
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 'danger'
END AS tr_color,
CASE
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN mc.competencia
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = 0) THEN mc.competencia*-1
   WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) <> COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN mc.competencia
END AS campo_ordenacao


FROM movimento_cobranca AS mc
WHERE mc.matricula = 2035
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
      --tr_success
      WHEN (COALESCE(mc.valor_pago, 0.0) = COALESCE(mc.valor_devido, 0.0)) THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 END
      ,campo_ordenacao
```